# Мультитач VS Мультиэкран

Tags: unity3d, multi-touch

Работаем в `Unity 5.5.1` под `Win`.

Вопрос можно ли заставить работать из одной программы мультитач в мультиэкранном приложении?

Требуется создать приложение которое будет работать одновременно на нескольких экранах. Каждый экран  поддерживает мультитач до 10 касаний. Пока из всего оборудования что нами тестировалось, получалось, что одновременно мультитачем можно пользоваться только на одном экране. Из-за чего ограничения не понятно, то ли это `Windows`, то ли драйвера тача, то ли это ограничения `Unity`. Единственное решение которое пока видится делать на каждый экран свой комп и соединяться по сети.

Для проверки мультитача собирали программу на `Unity`, которая опрашивала все`Input.touches` на каждом кадре и для каждого через UI рисовала в его позиции кружочек под пальцем.

Приобретали для проекта интерактивные столы, в них были установлены инфракрасные рамки. Наше приложение показало что рамка определяет 10 тач-касаний. Но при этом каждый тач обрабатывается системой как тач на главном экране, при этом совсем не важно каким назначен сенсорный экран. Также задавал вопрос в одной оптовой компании торгующей сенсорными экранами, мне там также сказали что рамки все работают как тач на главном экране. Тесты запускались под `Windows 7,8,10`.

Недавно получили сенсорный экран `Liliput`. Вместе с ноутбуком `Lenovo` также имеющим сенсорный экран он заработал в паре как дополнительный монитор, при этом тачи определялись каждый на своем экране. Но при использовании одного экрана, касания на другом не опознавались. Также пробовали `Liliput` определять как основной, а у ноута экран как дополнительный. Результат тот же.

Как проверяли: запустили наше приложение под `Unity` в оконном режиме и  разместили его одной половиной на одном экране, другой на втором. По отдельности мультитач работает на обjих экранах, но стоит на одном зажать тач, как на втором тач касания перестают опознаваться. Вторым тестом запустили две копии этого приложения, каждую на своем экране. Результат тот же, при зажатом таче на одном экране, на втором касания не опознаются.

Может кому уже приходилось сталкиваться с подобными вопросами? Есть возможность реализации с использованием одного системника на все экраны?

Comment: Мало данных, какая версия win, что конкретно не получается? Пример кода реализации.

Comment: Расписал чуточку подробнее. В коде ничего необычного нет, если очень хочется могу завтра добавить код.

Comment: для начала по базам, вы активировали дополнительные мониторы? (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html). На каждый дисплей нужна своя камера. 
Еще есть обсуждения по этому поводу( https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/5-3-multi-display-feature-issues.372604/   ), актуальные страницы со 2ой, тоже обсуждение проблем с использованием нескольких мониторов и одного UI.

Comment: Обязательно завтра сделаю несколько экспериментов, посмотрю что из этого получится